# Full text search in Nautilus 3.26.1 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nautilus, tracker

Full text search in Nautilus (3.26.1 in Ubuntu 18.04) does not work for me.

I installed tracker and it works correctly.

> When I type the "tracker search < something >" in a terminal window it
>   finds every files which contains "< something >".

What is wrong?

Should I install additional packages?

Should I set something in `dconf` (or elsewhere)?

Comment: Do you text from Home or somewhere else?

Comment: Recursive search is set for $Home. Originally $Home was in "index-single-directories" in `dconf` , but I deleted it from there, deleted everything from "index-recursive-directories" and put there $Home.

Comment: So it still searches correctly but it doesn't search anything that contains the word that is being searched?

Comment: For example, if i searched `Downloads` it comes up with `Downloads` but not with anything like `Test Download.txt`?

Comment: It searches only the filenames, and it finds also the `Test Download.txt`, but it doesn't find the words inside the file `Test Download.txt`

Comment: oh... ill try to help and find something to help you

Comment: I made a fresh install in virtualbox and installed tracker. Full text search doesn't work. Should it work? Does anyone work?

Comment: Maybe it is a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1767817

Comment: It's not a bug. I don't think there is a full text search?

Comment: You'll have to install an addon or something? Maybe a new file manager?

Comment: Full test search have worked in 17.10 (allegedly ).